# Работа с датой в GridView

Tags: yii2

Новичек в yii и возник вопрос. Существует два столбца с датами(начало подписки и конец подписки). Необходимо, чтобы конец подписки вычислялся сам на основе данных из столбца с началом подписки, при этом был выбор между подпиской на 1 месяц или 3.

Answer (score 0):

И в чем проблема добавить 1 или 3 месяца к существующей дате?

```
// Создали объект с известной датой начала подписки
$date = new DateTime('2000-12-31');
// Создали интервал в 1 месяц
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');

// Добавили интервал к существующей дате
$date->add($interval);
echo $date->format('d.m.y');
```

Comment: В том, что необходимо в GridView выбирать между 1 месяцем и 3. Я новичек и не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Я сейчас не понял, что надо сделать. Если переключатель, то в колонку надо добавить радиобаттоны и с помощью js отслеживать их изменение. Какой радиобаттон выбрали, такую дату и показали. Даты можно выводить сразу две, одну из них скрывать.

Comment: а можно привести простой пример радиобаттонов? Я просто с этим не знаком